# How to put single quotes in bash

Tags: bash

```
ABcD!987zyz12388
```

I'd like to put single quotes around it to handle special character/s. This password is fetched and saved to a variable.

```
$mypass=`fetchpwd $sourceserver $loginacct`;
$mypass="'$mypass'";

print "My password is: $mypass\n";
```

The return looks like this

```
My Password is 'ABcD!987zyz12388
'
```

Comment: That doesn’t look like Bash. And if I turn it into Bash it works fine.

Comment: Similar, though Perl (or maybe PHP?) seems a better match.

Comment: Do you have a carriage return at the end of `$mypass` perhaps? In Bash, what do you see for `declare -p mypass`?

Comment: ‘_put single quotes around it to handle special character_’ sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Also, even more of an issue that your password contains a newline character, it seems.

Comment: `declare -p varname` is a useful way to inspect the contents of a variable.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That would be an issue with the code, though, not the password. A  user's choice of passwords should not be dictated by incorrect string handling of a program that handles the password.

Comment: Please clarify what language you are using to construct and execute the shell command you have mentioned in comments to my answer. This appears to *not* be a primarily `bash`-related question, and the right answer will likely bypass `bash` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes don't belong in the variable itself; they should be added by the `printf` statement that displays the value.

```
mypass=$(fetchpwd "$sourceserver" "$logginacct")
printf "My password is: '%s'\n" "$mypass"
```

Comment: I need the password with '' ( single quotes ) to pass as a parameter to access the dataserver. Example:  isql -U sybase_user -P 'ABcD!987zyz12388'  ....  Without the single quotes, the access fails because of the special char !

Comment: No, you don't. `isql -U sybase_user -P "$mypass"`, not `isql -U sybase_user -P $mypass`. The quotes are not part of the variable value, but part of the shell command.

Comment: mypass=`fetchpwd $sourceserver $loginacct`;  fetchpwd is a sub-function to retrieve the password from the vault.   mypass=$(`fetchpwd $sourceserver $loginacct`) is what I should do?

Comment: Yes, just as I've shown (with the quotes). `$(...)` is an improved syntax for command substitutions that obsoletes the use of backticks.

Comment: I also noticed that this fetchpwd is adding an extra line. $mypass=`fetchpwd $sourceserver $loginacct`;  My Password is 'ABcD!987zyz12388
'  . How to remove the extra line in the output? In perl I can use chomp to remove the extra line.

Comment: How exactly are you determining that? Command substitutions strip trailing line feeds from the result of the command. If `fetchpwd` emits DOS line endings, then the *carriage return* is preserved, but carriage returns don't typically appear as line feeds when you write them to the terminal.

Comment: mypass=$(fetchpwd "$sourceserver" "$logginacct") ;  mypass='$mypass'  Can I do this so that the password is now enclosed in single quotes?

Comment: No, that just assigns the literal string `$mypass` to `mypass`. *You don't need to put the quotes in the value.* That is not how quoting works in the shell. All you need to do is double quote the parameter expansion, and any special characters in the result will be passed literally as part of the argument, not subject to processing by the shell.

Comment: + loaddb_pwd='TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S'
+ loaddbpwd=''\''TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S'\'''
+ printf 'Password is '\''TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S'\'' '
Password is 'TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S' + isql -U syb_dba -w200 -P ''\''TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S'\''' -S MyServer
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'MyServer':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:    The password got enclosed in quotes but then it got enclosed with "\" and the first ' was missing.   What I am trying to accomplish something like this isql -U syb_dba -w200 -P 'TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S' -S MyServer

Comment: I really don't know how many different ways I can say "Don't put quotes in the variable value." Have you even *tried* doing what I say to do in the first comment?

Comment: `loaddb_pwd='TsKq=PiXnuo>Q6S'; isql -U syb_dba -w200 -P "$loaddb_pwd" -S MyServer`

Comment: If it weren't for the `>` in the password, you wouldn't need quotes *anywhere*; `loaddb_pwd=TsKq=PiXnuoQ6S; isql -U syb_dba -w200 -P $loaddb_pwd -S MyServer` would work just fine. (But using quotes *properly* avoids problems without having to know if they are strictly *necessary*.)

Comment: This password TsKq=PiXnuoQ6S needs to be enclosed because of the db software is not accepting special char. The password needs to be enclosed 'TsKq=PiXnuoQ6S' . I followed your suggestion and the password is enclosed with quotes but once it is used in the command line as -P "$loaddb_pwd" , the single quotes are getting omitted .

Comment: Are you trying to construct a command line to pass as an argument to *another* command that executes it?

Comment: Yes. First is to get the password from the vault and must enclosed it with single quotes to handle the special character and save it as variable.  Using this variable, it will be passed in the command line like this isql -U syb_dba -w200 -P "$loaddb_pwd" -S MyServer . But somehow, the " are getting stripped hence failing to log into the dataserver.

Comment: Then provide the context in which you are trying to execute the constructed command. The quotes are *still* part of the shell command, not the password, and if possible, there should be a way to execute the command without involving a shell at all (which would eliminate the need to quote the password).

Comment: Would it be possible to invoke it like this (backslash)`isql -U syb_dba -w200 -S MyServer<<EOF "$loaddb_pwd" `(backslash)EOF

Comment: That depends on what language you are actually using to *construct* the shell command. (I should have pressed this harder earlier, but you are actually using something like Perl or PHP?)

Comment: I inherited this script. It starts with a ksh then fork a perl script then from perl will call the bash script.  The issue started when the password policy got changed to include special characters and data processing got disrupted. I got the ksh and perl fixed but it's the bash where I am having difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

If `fetchpwd` is adding an extra newline you can remove newlines using

```
mypass=$(fetchpwd "$sourceserver" "$logginacct" | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that `$mypass=...` won't work as that's not a valid variable name (identifier).

Comment: The command substitution would already remove any trailing newlines. The `tr -d` should not be necessary. (In fact, it will *incorrectly* remove any linefeeds that actually occur in the password.) (Yes, a password could in theory contain a linefeed.)

Comment: (And yes, the command substitution's practice of trimming trailing linefeeds would also be a problem if the password actually ended with a linefeed, and should probably be addressed in my own answer.)